# Unable to integrate text editor into Moodle 2

Tags: ckeditor, moodle

I have not been able to integrate CkEditor with Moodle 2.9.1+.  (I suspect the issue would apply to any text editor, not just CkEditor.)

Per the [README instructions](https://github.com/electrolinux/moodle-ckeditor), I cloned `moodle-ckeditor` from https://github.com/electrolinux/moodle-ckeditor into the `lib/editor` directory of the moodle installation I administer.

I renamed the downloaded directory from `moodle-ckeditor` to `ckeditor`.

I added this line to `config.php` in the root moodle directory:

```
$CFG->texteditors='ckeditor,tinymce,htmlarea';
```

When I navigate  to Admin > Plugins > Text editors > Manage editors, I only see the original 3 editors: TinyMCS HTML editor, Plain text area, and Atto HTML editor.

FWIW, when I experimentally removed `"tinymce,"` from the shown line of `config.php`,  it still showed up on the "Manage editors" page.  That makes me think that `$CFG->texteditors` is not being used.  I do know it is being read, because I get an error on the "Manage editors" page if I put a syntax error into that line.

I've appended a console session in case to call attention to or rule out mistakes due to typos, permissions, etc.:

```
[~/public_html]# grep ckeditor config.php
$CFG->texteditors='ckeditor,tinymce,htmlarea';
[~/public_html]# ls -l lib/editor
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 millscso millscso 4096 Jul 23 16:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 48 millscso millscso 4096 Jul 16 02:16 ../
drwxr-xr-x  9 millscso millscso 4096 Jul 16 02:16 atto/
drwxr-xr-x  5 millscso millscso 4096 Jul 23 16:09 ckeditor/
drwxr-xr-x  7 millscso millscso 4096 Jul 23 15:59 ckeditor-/
-rw-r--r--  1 millscso millscso    0 Jul 16 02:16 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  3 millscso millscso 4096 Jul 16 02:16 textarea/
drwxr-xr-x  9 millscso millscso 4096 Jul 16 02:16 tinymce/
```

**Update**

A few days after reverting the change to `config.php`, "CKEditor HTML editor" began showing up within Admin > Plugins > Text editors > Manage editors.  Unfortunately, when I click on Settings [http://mills-cs.org/admin/settings.php?section=editorsettingsckeditor], I get a [Section error](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/error/admin/sectionerror).

Comment: It has been a LONG time since I have done anything with Moodle, but is there a place to "clear the cache" or "refresh all plugins" or something like that? Administrative buttons inside the Moodle control panel?

Comment: @rlb.usa Thanks for the reply. I am not aware of a refresh feature, but I tried putting the site into maintenance mode, then out of maintenance mode, without effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me with Moodle 2.7, here's what I did

1. git clone https://github.com/electrolinux/moodle-ckeditor.git
2. copied and pasted the folder /moodle-ckeditor/ into moodlewww/lib/editor/
3. renamed moodlewww/lib/editor/moodle-ckeditor/ to moodlewww/lib/editor/ckeditor/
4. Logged into my site and clicked on site admin -> notifications to install ckeditor
5. I skipped $CFG->texteditors='ckeditor,tinymce,htmlarea';
6. Instead went to site admin -> plugins -> editors -> manage editors then *enabled* ckeditor - this might be what's wrong in your case?
7. Then moved ckeditor up the list so it is first.

UPDATE:

I tried with an install of 2.9 and it failed because the version.php file is missing - I'm guessing this is a requirement in 2.9.

I always have the debugger on development. You might find it useful too, have these settings in `config.php`

```
// Developer settings - not for production!
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$CFG->debug = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

So I created the missing file `/lib/editor/ckeditor/version.php` with the contents below and it installed correctly in 2.9

```
<?php
// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/**
 * CKEditor text editor integration version file.
 *
 * @package    editor_ckeditor
 * @copyright  
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$plugin->version   = 2015073000;        // The current plugin version (Date: YYYYMMDDXX)
$plugin->requires  = 2015051100;        // Requires this Moodle version
$plugin->component = 'editor_ckeditor';  // Full name of the plugin (used for diagnostics)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  I had not done step 4, but, when I did just now, it didn't show anything about ckeditor.  I did verify that everything was up to date.  I had enabled ckeditor and did so again.  I still get the Section error.

Comment: Updated the answer for you :)

Comment: THANK YOU so much.  You earned not only 100 well-deserved reputation but also the gratitude of a teacher and her students.  Do you want to make the pull request into ckeditor, or should I?

Comment: No problem at all :) glad to be of help - you can make the pull request if you like, you found the bug ;)

Comment: You go ahead.  If you want to make an even bigger contribution, update it to a recent version of CKEditor. :-)